# Ignoring files from Android APK

Tags: java, android, apk

Is it possible to ignore files from being packaged into the Android APK? For instance, I have my .psd files in the same folder as their .png counterparts, and all the .psd files get packaged up.

I know I can move them outside of the folder, but I like having them in all together and would prefer not to if possible

Answer (score 14, accepted):

This is actually supported in the Android Asset Packaging Tool (AAPT).

I always put my psd-like files in the resource directories like this:

```
/res/drawable/_pre_production/ic_launcher.psd
```

Any `_pre_production` directory will not be added to the APK.

With this approach they're in a sub-directory of the actual images' directory, but I don't see the problem with that. It is still neatly organized. ;)

Comment: Didn't know, a little hidden gem there :)

Comment: +1 for a ADT-solution (it's briefly mentioned in the [documentation](http://developer.android.com/design/style/iconography.html) but it can easily be overlooked). Actually having your original files in a subfolder of res/ is great. I'm using a Photoshop-Script to generate all resolutions and distribute them to the corresponding folders.

Comment: Brilliant. Thanks, Roger. Is this properly documented anywhere?

Answer (score 2):

An Ant script will do the trick. If you are using proguard, even that script may be good enough for u.

Comment: The Ant script sounds like what I'm looking for. Can you give me any examples or a link that might explain how to write them? I keep searching for it on Google but I can't seem to find any good information.

Answer (score 2):

Use the Maven Android Plugin and declare your resources with a matching pattern that excluded the relevant file types you dont want added (e.g. **/*.psd). Check out the [documentation for the resource plugin](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-resources-plugin/examples/include-exclude.html) and look at the M[aven Android Plugin Samples project](http://code.google.com/p/maven-android-plugin/wiki/Samples) .. specifically the MorseFlash application I created and the resource plugin related setup.

Answer (score 0):

You can try using the [maven android plugin](http://code.google.com/p/maven-android-plugin/) and adding some logic to the build phase.

Answer (score -2):

If you are using Eclipse, right-click the file and select "Exclude from build path"

Comment: This is not available, at least in Eclipse 3.5.2