# include/exclude files in apk

Tags: android, eclipse, apk

In an android eclipse project, I have a directory like assets/gfx. In this directory are files like mysprite.png, but I also have mysprite.xcf, the original gimp file. Is this file included in the apk file, and if so, is there a way to exclude it from the build of the apk file?

Comment: Yes the file will be included in the apk. One way to exclude the file would be to delete it from assets folder.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Ignoring files from Android APK](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4789187/ignoring-files-from-android-apk)

Comment: Yes, this is essentially the same question. Thanks for pointing it out.

Answer (score 1):

First, yes. this files are present in your apk as well as /res files.

Second, no. You cannot modify apk contents(delete, add, ..). You may keep them (for example picture) on SD card

Comment: Thanks for the replies. I'm not seeking to modify the apk contents, but rather dictate what goes into the apk in the first place. This can be done in a C/C++ makefile, for example.