# How to keep files like *.scala and *.txt from being included in my apk files?

Tags: android, scala, ant, intellij-idea

I'm attempting to write an Android application in Scala using IntelliJ IDEA.  I'm able to get the apk built and running just fine, but I'm noticing files being added to my apk that shouldn't be there.  For example, all of my scala source files are being included as well as rootdoc.txt from the scala library jar.

I'm using the default ant build system setup provided by the android sdk.  I'm trying to avoid using SBT if possible.

Comment: Possibly solved here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4789187/ignoring-files-from-android-apk

Comment: > "I'm trying to avoid using SBT if possible." — Why? SBT is a good thing for Scala.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Flo said, this has been solved. You can either set up an `ant script` or use a `Maven` plugin to set it up. Alternatively you could use the `drawable/_pre_production/` folder which wont get compiled into the jar.