# Excluding files from compilation

Tags: android, compilation, apk

I have a number of files in a project that I don't want to include in the compiled apk.

For source files, right-click -> Build Path -> Exclude does the trick.

How about for excluding other files, for example certain ones in the assets folder? If my understanding is correct, all of these are included in the apk by default.

Also, if I create a custom folder in my project structure (e.g. inside the assets onee) it will show in the package explorer. Would its contents be added to the apk?

Comment: Files and folders inside the assets folder will be included. Your own folders on the same level as assets folder not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently, folders named `_pre_production` are not added to the `APK`.

I cannot take credit for this. Here is where I found the answer:

[Ignoring files from Android APK](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4789187/ignoring-files-from-android-apk)

I'm duplicating the answer here in case someone comes by.